# Regex to find code blocks from book page

Tags: java, regex

I have text from programming book and I need to parse it to get code and text blocks.

Text Example:

> If this test evaluates to false (meaning that the bicycle is not in
>   motion), control jumps to the end of the if-then statement. In
>   addition, the opening and closing braces are optional, provided that
>   the "then" clause contains only one statement:
>
> ```
> void applyBrakes() {
>     // same as above, but without braces
>     if (isMoving)
>         currentSpeed--;
> }
> ```

I need help with regex to find all code blocks in this text.

Comment: Code blocks can extend across lines or be in a single line. Its not wise to do this using regex

Comment: you can check http://regexr.com/ is very cool to understand the regex that are trying to do and you can put some text to test it :)

Comment: What if the code block contains a large multi-line comment that looks just like a paragraph from the book? What I'm trying to say: This is very hard, and probably not easy to get right, much less with regex. Your best bet might be to take all lines that are indented or something like that.

Comment: Just an idea: when you enter a question here at StackOverflow, containing source code in a particular language, and you mention that language in the list of keywords, then automatically the pieces of code are rendered using syntax highlighting. Maybe you can contact StackOverflow moderators about how this is done? Otherwise there are quite some text editors using syntax highlighting. If you find an open-source one, you might learn from this?